AWS Cost Usage for 6 months fields
Has any one worked on the AWS Cost and Usage?
We are using the get_cost_and_usage but there are product related fields which the api doesn't fetch. We are able to get blendedcost, unblendedcost, usagestartdate, service, location but there is no direct api to fetch:

UsageAccountId
ProductCode
ResourceId
SKU

We used the GetCostAndUsageWithResources - AWS Billing and Cost Management but it can fetch only for 14 days we need to fetch this detail for 6 months of the historic data.
 [
                    **'UsageAccountId'**,
                    'BlendedCost',  
                    'UnblendedCost',
                    'UsageStartDate',
                    'BundledDiscount',
                   **** 'ProductCode'**,**
                    **'ProductName**',
                   ** 'ResourceId',**
                    'Servicename',
                   ** 'SKU',**
                    'Unit',
                    'Location'
]

As of now we need to handle the details from the first one month details by handling in the boto3 code by handling the csv files and segregate the Resource and SKU details. Is there any other way of handling it?

Are you familiar with AWS Cloud Intelligence Lab?
https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/cloud-intelligence-dashboards/
It uses Athena and quicksight to show you your costs, integrated directly with the CUR. Instead of querying the CE API, you could just use your boto3 to query athena directly, getting all the information you need, based on resources and the CUR full information.
You can follow the deployment guide here, it is a very simple process to deploy it:
https://catalog.workshops.aws/awscid/en-US/dashboards/foundational/cudos-cid-kpi/deploy
